# How can I create a lightbox with text and image?

Tags: wordpress

I am not good at programming. I am trying to create an image gallery with lightbox and content in it.
[image: it looks something like that]

I am looking for a plugin for this kind of function.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a similar type of popup using the free [WordPress Colorbox plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-colorbox/). It is a simple lightbox plugin for WordPress that allows users to pop up content in lightbox using the popular jQuery ColorBox library. You can also view the larger version of a particular media file without having to leave the page.

### Features

- Supports photos, grouping, slideshow, ajax, inline, and iframed content
- Lightweight: 10KB of JavaScript (less than 5KBs gzipped)
- Appearance is controlled through CSS so it can be restyled
- Can be extended with callbacks & event-hooks without altering the source files
- Completely unobtrusive, options are set in the JS and require no changes to existing HTML
- Preloads upcoming images in a photo group
- Apply lightbox effect on images inserted into WordPress post/page
- Responsive lightbox popup which works on mobile devices (It fits perfectly on smaller screens)

### How to open an image in lightbox

Create a new post/page and use the following shortcode to create a text/image link which will open the image in lightbox once clicked:

`[wp_colorbox_media url="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/images/overlay.jpg" type="image" hyperlink="click here to pop up image"]`

Comment: if i would like to create a something like gallery as well can i still use this?